# angular 4 HTTP Client casting type response

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

In my angular 4 project I am using HTTP Client, when I have a GET call the response is sometimes articulated so I have to do something like:

```
 this.loggedUser.name = response._embedded.agent.name
```

But in this case I have this error:

> Property '_embedded' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse'

I resolve the problem with casting the response to any:

```
getLoggedUser(url) {
return this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'})
.map((response) => <any>response);
}
```

So, Did I have to cast to any all the response?
Is this considered good practice, or should I be doing something else?

Comment: Change like this .map((response) =>response.json()); then subscribe to get the value.

Comment: @Sreemat Property 'json' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse<Object>'.

Comment: Can you explain what is this {observe: 'response'}

Comment: to read full response: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpResponse<T>` class does not have any `_embedded` property indeed. That is why you get the compiler error, since Typescript statically typed your response to `HttpResponse<Object>` (the generic type argument is meant for the `body` property of the response).

Casting the response to `<any>` seems like a feasible solution in this case, if you know to expect the `_embedded` prop there at any time. A null check might be a nice addition though.

Here is the `HttpResponse<T>` typing for reference:

```
/**
 * A full HTTP response, including a typed response body (which may be `null`
 * if one was not returned).
 *
 * `HttpResponse` is a `HttpEvent` available on the response event
 * stream.
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export declare class HttpResponse<T> extends HttpResponseBase {
    /**
     * The response body, or `null` if one was not returned.
     */
    readonly body: T | null;
    /**
     * Construct a new `HttpResponse`.
     */
    constructor(init?: {
        body?: T | null;
        headers?: HttpHeaders;
        status?: number;
        statusText?: string;
        url?: string;
    });
    readonly type: HttpEventType.Response;
    clone(): HttpResponse<T>;
    clone(update: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders;
        status?: number;
        statusText?: string;
        url?: string;
    }): HttpResponse<T>;
    clone<V>(update: {
        body?: V | null;
        headers?: HttpHeaders;
        status?: number;
        statusText?: string;
        url?: string;
    }): HttpResponse<V>;
}
```